# Counting names in CSV files

Tags: c#, loops, csv, iteration, counting

I am trying to write a program for a school project that will read a csv file containing a name on each line and output each name and the number of times it occurrences in a list box. I would prefer for it not to be pre set for a specific name but i guess that would work also. So far i have this but now I'm stuck. The CSV file will have a name on each line and also have a coma after each name. Any help would be great thanks.

This is what I have so far:

```
string[] csvArray;
string line;
StreamReader reader;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

//set filter for dialog control
const string FILTER = "CSV Files|*.csv|All Files|*.*";
openFileDialog.Filter = FILTER;

//if user opens file and clicks ok
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //open input file
    reader = File.OpenText(openFileDialog.FileName);

    //while not end of stream
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        //read line from file
        line = reader.ReadLine().ToLower();

        //split values
        csvArray = line.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Linq we can do the following:

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<int,string>> CountOccurences(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    return data.GroupBy(t => t).Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Count(),t.Key));     
}
```

Test:

```
var strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("John");
strings.Add("John");
strings.Add("John");
strings.Add("Peter");
strings.Add("Doe");
strings.Add("Doe");
foreach (var item in CountOccurences(strings)) {
    Console.WriteLine (String.Format("{0} = {1}", item.Item2, item.Item1));
}
```

> John = 3
>   Peter = 1
>   Doe = 2

To use in your case:

```
string filePath = "c:\myfile.txt"
foreach (var item in CountOccurences(File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(t => t.Split(',').First())))
    Console.WriteLine (String.Format("{0} = {1}", item.Item2, item.Item1));
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a dictionary, where you can store the occurrence of each Name:

```
Dictionary<string,int> NameOcur=new Dictionary<string,int>();
...
 while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        //read line from file
        line = reader.ReadLine().ToLower();

        //split values
        csvArray = line.Split(',');
        if (NameOcur.ContainsKey(csvArray[0]))
        {
          ///Name exists in Dictionary increase count
           NameOcur[csvArray[0]]++;
        }
        else
        {
          //Does not exist add with value 1
           NameOcur.Add(csvArray[0],1);
        }
     }
```